# Wikipedia Page Rank Example

Tags: algorithm, pagerank

Is the following example taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank#Algorithm) for pagerank correct for page A?

[image]

As far as the algorithm goes it should be approximately half of the value of page D with a standard damping factor of 0.85. What is wrong here?